# How to efficiently compare two vectors in C++, whose content can't be meaningfully sorted?

Tags: c++

How to efficiently compare two vectors in C++, whose content can't be meaningfully sorted?

I read many posts but most talk about first sorting the two vectors and then comparing
the elements. But in my case I can't sort the vectors in a meaningful way that can
help the comparison. That means I will have to do an O(N^2) operation rather than O(N),
I will have to compare each element from the first vector and try to find a unique match
for it in the second vector. So I will have to match up all the elements and if I can
find a unique match for each then the vectors are equal.

Is there an efficient and simple way to do this? Will I have to code it myself?

Edit: by **meaningful sorting** I mean a way to sort them so that later you can
compare them in linear fashion.

Thank you

Comment: If the elements are truly incomparable, then I can't see how it can be done faster than `O(n^2)`. However, if you describe what kinds of elements you are dealing with, maybe we can suggest a way to sort them.

Comment: What do you mean by 'meaningful', it doesn't have to be meaningful, just consistent

Comment: It does not really matter the kinds of elements, what matters is they can't be sorted in any meaningful way so that you could later compare them in linear fashion. I guess I will need two loops and compare each element with each other. Argh...

Comment: By meaningful I mean, you can't sort them, so that you can later compare them in a linear fashion. I mean, there is no such sort criteria, this is due to the members they contain basically.

Comment: You could provide some sort of hash for the objects and pre-sort the vectors on the hashes.

Comment: @user2381422 People are trying to politely tell you that you are probably wrong; there is most likely *some* consistent way of ordering them, even if it has little to do with the meaning of the data.

Comment: Never mind, I remembered that you could use hashmaps - see my answer.

Comment: No there is no way to sort them so that you can compare linearly later.

Comment: Not to be all MATH, but given a set of distinct elements, you can always impose a total ordering. Given a set with non-distinct elements, you can always impose a strict weak ordering (what the operator< needs to be for sort in C++). Can you give more information about the contents of the elements of the vector?

Comment: @user2381422 You need to realise that you are almost certainly wrong here. But we can help you with the *how* only if you give us more information.

Comment: @user2381422 By not giving any more information, your question essentially becomes "Believe me this is the only way to do this. Is there any other way to do this?"

Comment: Come on, you can *distinguish* between objects. Take it a step further and impose some made up completely artificial but consistent order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the elements can be *hashed* in some meaningful way, you can get expected `O(n)` performance by using a hashmap: Insert all elements from list A into the hashmap, and for each element in list B, check if it exists in the hashmap.

In C++, I believe that `unordered_map` is the standard hashmap implementation (though I haven't used it myself).

Comment: `O(n)` time, but `3*n` memory occupation. Would this work on very (very) large inputs?

Comment: @xgbi O(n) memory occupation. The two input arrays should not be considered, only the hash

Comment: @xgbi: That's a valid point - however, as @Enigma points out, `3 * n` is still `O(n)`, so it isn't very prohibitive.

Answer (score 5):

1. Put all elements of vector `A` into a hash table, where the element is the key, and the value is a counter of how many times you’ve added the element. [O(n) expected]
2. Iterate over vector `B` and decrease the counters in the hash table for each element. [O(n) expected]
3. Iterate over the hash table and check that each counter is 0. [O(n) expected]

= O(n) expected runtime.

Answer (score 1):

No reason to use a map, since there's no values to associate with, just keys (the elements themselves). In this case you should look at using a `set` or an `unordered_set`. Put all elements from A into a new set, and then loop through B. For each element, `if( set.find(element) == set.end() ) return false;`

If you're set on sorting the array against some arbitrary value, you might want to look at C++11's `hash`, which returns a size_t. Using this you can write a comparator which hashes the two objects and compares them, which you can use with std::sort to perform a O(n log n) sort on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't sort the vectors you could try this. C++ gurus please free to point out flaws, obvious failures to exploit STL and other libraries, failures to comprehend previous answers, etc, etc :) Apologies in advance as necessary.

Have a vector of ints, 0..n, called C. These ints are the indices of each element in vector B. For each element in vector A compare it against elements in B according to the B indices that are in C. If you find a match remove that index from C. C is now one shorter. For the next A you're again searching B according to indices in C, which being one shorter, takes less time. And if you get lucky it will be quite quick.

Or you could build up a vector of B indices that you have already checked so that you ignore those B's next time round the loop. Saves building a complete C first.